# Action bar search suggestion with blank data

Tags: android

The Below code is for the suggestion in the action bar.
the data is displayed as the blank. but the data is available on selection.
i am not able to figure out what is wrong. can somebody help me.

[image]

****//search suggestion in the menu****

```
    SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        final SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search_dashboard).getActionView();    
        final SearchView.SearchAutoComplete autoComplete = (SearchView.SearchAutoComplete) searchView.findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.search_src_text);
        autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        final ArrayAdapter<Steps> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Steps>(this, R.layout.load_text_view, R.id.load_text,stepsList);
        autoComplete.setAdapter(adapter);
        searchView.setOnSuggestionListener(new SearchView.OnSuggestionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionSelect(int position) {
                return true;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean onSuggestionClick(int position) {
                 //clicked
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

//menu

```
     <item
            android:id="@+id/search_dashboard"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
            android:title="@string/search"
            appcompat:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
            android:visible="true"
            app:showAsAction="always" />
```

//the load text view

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_text"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/card_background"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys i found the problem.

```
//changed this and it works
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/load_text"
    style="?android:attr/dropDownItemStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorWhite"
    android:textColor="@color/colorTranslucentBlack"
    android:maxLines="2"
    android:minHeight="?android:attr/listPreferredItemHeight"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLargePopupMenu"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_size" />
```

Answer (score 0):

To go for the obvious, is the text on the suggestion white?

Comment: but how will the user know its the suggested text

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you. I'm asking if the suggested text is the same colour as it's background.

Answer (score 0):

You set text color white in autocomplete.Change text color from white to another color. Change this line in your code

```
autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
```

Comment: the autoComplete.setTextColor(Color.WHITE); is for the autoComplete not for the suggestion

Comment: Have you setThreshold on autocomplete?